# ConfirmDialog class not found

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

The [Confirm Dialog](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-confirm-dialog/) class seems to be missing in V19, even installing the component itself.

I suspect it was replaced by something else. Any idea of what can have replaced it?

Comment: Can you please [edit] this and ask a question that might be answerable by the Stack Overflow community? Currently, this is just reads as a statement of fact, not a question.

Comment: If this is the case, why do you not create a ticket in a support channel? If you are not sure, please turn this into a proper question, where you show what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: No it's not missing. It's still there. Please provide a reproducible example where you don't find it

Comment: Thanks Simon, I created a simple project to reproduce the case and I am opening a ticket. If the class is expected to exist it shall be addressed by tech support. Issue #12286.

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml? At the very least, the `<dependencyManagement>` and `<dependencies>` blocks may be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vaadin Confirm Dialog *was part of Vaadin's commercial Pro offering, which requires subscription to use prior to version 23.2*. Thus if you use `vaadin-bom` in `vaadin-core` configuration, it is not included. Thus you need to change dependency from `vaadin-core` to `vaadin` like below

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 .
```

..

Note: license policy of the component has been changed.